# How to access an Objective-C NSMutableDictionary from a Swift class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have an Objective-C controller called `linkedinlogincontroller`. Inside that controller I have an `NSMutableDictionary` called `result`.

Simply, all I need to know is what is the best practice way of having access to that dictionary in a Swift controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Look at this link:**
[Using Objective C & Swift together.](http://mobiforge.com/design-development/using-objective-c-and-swift-together-ios-apps)

Expose the ObjectiveC class in `<YourProjectName>-Bridging-Header.h`.

```
#import "linkedinlogincontroller.h"
```

ObjectiveC Header

```
//  linkedinlogincontroller.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface linkedinlogincontroller : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary * result;
@end
```

ObjectiveC Implementation

```
//  linkedinlogincontroller.m
#import "linkedinlogincontroller.h"
#import "<YourProjectName>-Swift.h"

@implementation linkedinlogincontroller

...
    self.result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"key":@"value"}];
    NSLog(@"Print from Objc %@", self.result);
    YourSwiftClass * so = [[YourSwiftClass alloc] init];
    [so printFromSwift:self];
...
```

Swift Implementation

```
//  YourSwiftClass.swift
import Foundation

@objc class YourSwiftClass : NSObject {
    func printFromSwift(vc:linkedinlogincontroller) {
        println ("Print from Swift \(vc.result)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to use it like a swift dictionary. To access an element in it:

```
linkedinlogincontroller.result[key]
```

should work fine.

Comment: When I try this line var appuserid = LinkedInLoginController.result[AppUserID] I get an unresolved identifier 'AppUserID' and that is the correct key from my dictionary. Have any clue about this error?

Comment: is AppUserID declared properly? Is it the correct type for your dictionary key? If it's a literal string, make sure you put it in quotes. Seeing more of your code might help.